# Meaning of a hyphen as a special parameter?

Tags: bash

From https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html,

> `-` (A hyphen.) Expands to the current option flags as specified upon invocation, by the set builtin command, or those set by the shell
>   itself (such as the -i option).

I am not sure what it says. Can you give some examples for the meaning of a hyphen parameter?

Comment: [Find out what your shell’s flags are](http://www.chainsawonatireswing.com/2012/02/02/find-out-what-your-unix-shells-flags-are-then-change-them//?from=@)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can `echo $-` to see the currently-enabled shell options:

```
$ echo $-
himBH
```

Those are options you can provide with a `-` on shell invocation — `bash -h -B` — or later on using [`set`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin).

The flags are defined in [the documentation for `set`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin). My options above are:

> - `-h`
>     Locate and remember (hash) commands as they are looked up
>     for execution. This option is enabled by default.
> - `-m`
>     Job control is enabled (see [Job Control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control)). All processes
>     run in a separate process group. When a background job
>     completes, the shell prints a line containing its exit status.
> - `-B`
>     The shell will perform brace expansion (see [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion)).
>     This option is on by default.
> - `-H`
>     Enable ‘!’ style history substitution (see [History
>     Interaction](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction)). This option is on by default for interactive shells.

and [`i` for an interactive shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Invoking-Bash).

If I change the active options, say with `set -x`, I'll get a new value of `$-`:

```
$ set -x +h
$ echo $-
imxBH
```

Comment: Thanks. What are the differences between "the current option flags as specified upon invocation" and "those set by the shell itself (such as the -i option)"?

Comment: The latter are inherent properties of the shell that it exposes to you. You don't have to ask for `-i` to be in an interactive shell, or to be disabled in a non-interactive shell. Some of the others, like `c`, are more interesting - you *can't* `set -c` at run time at all, but `bash -c 'echo $-'` will include the flag.

Answer (score 4):

It depends - as a dollar-sign expansion, `$-` expands to a list of the current shell's `set`table single-letter options - such as `-x` and `-f` and `-C`. For an example, an interactive shell will expand it *at least* like:

```
echo "$-"
```

---

```
i
```

The longer, `set -o option` versions can be had with `set +o.`

But there is another kind of *hyphen-special-parameter* which is a sort of analog to this. You can use *two* consecutive hyphens to signal the end of options in a typical command's argument list, but you can also use a single-hypen to do the same for a POSIX-shell. Historically, shells accepted a *single* hyphen to mean much the same.

A `bash` shell interprets a single-hyphen specially in argument list-contexts. With `set`, for example it marks the end of options *and* disables `-v`erbose and `-x`trace. Additionally, `set -` does *not* clear a parameter list if it is the first and only argument to `set` as `set --` would.

A login shell will often append a `-` to its `argv[0]`.

Comment: And in programs that take a list of filenames to process, a single `-` as an argument often means "process what's on stdin at this point in the list".

Comment: @zwol - maybe...